# How do i fetch $row data for colours and services

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to sort out a web portfolio but can't get my head around how I can implement it, if it can!

Basically what I'm after is...

On the portfolio page, list details of the client with their name, description, TAGS (html, css, photoshop, jquery etc), COLOURS USED (black, white, blue, green etc) and services used etc.

At the moment in my client table i have:
**"ID title description tags services colours client"**

With this current system I have to state all the colours and services all in one row, meaning I can't separate the contents to style it with css (see below).

**I'd like to be able to show the colours used by each project as 16x16 colour blocks and the services as a `<ul><li></li></ul>` list.

**Is this possible?**

My current script can be found here:
http://davidpottrell.co.uk/paste/portfolio.txt

What I'm after (found on right of image)
http://davidpottrell.co.uk/paste/todo.png

Comment: Of course it's possible. Sorry, but I can't see the problem you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');

$query = $db->query('SELECT * FROM client');
foreach($query as $row) {

    // I assume you're storing colours as a delimited string? (red,green,yellow)
    $colours = explode(',', $row['colours']);
    if (count($colours)) {
       foreach ($colours as $colour) {
            echo '<div class="colour_block" id="'.$colour.'"></div>';
       }
    }

    // Same thing with services
    $services = explode(',', $row['services']);
    if (count($services)) {
       echo '<ul>';
       foreach ($services as $service) {
            echo '<li id="'.$service.'">'.$service.'</div>';
       }
       echo '</ul>';
    }

}
```

Comment: My current script is connected to the database and all of the content is being echoed - How would I implement this?

My script can be found here:
http://davidpottrell.co.uk/paste/portfolio.txt

(I'm assuming what I have so far is correct :/)

Thanks for the help though, really do appreciate it!

Comment: Don't use `mysql_` functions - they'll be deprecated soon. Use PDO.

Comment: So best to simply change the top few lines to the new PDO function? Or are there more changes to be done? Quite annoying that I'm being taught this in university - and it's already deprecated. Lol...

Comment: The code you've supplied - Is there a way to implement it into my own work? Or would I have to build from scratch?

Comment: Just change the connection parameters with your own, and it should work. You'll need to replace your old code with this

Comment: That's it! It all works! I've added the extra fields and duplicated your code to work with tags as well. Perfect! - I do have one last question is there a PDO method for
`if(mysql_num_rows($result)==0) {
 echo "No Client Found";
}`

Answer (score 1):

How are you saving the services and colors at the moment? Do you write strings like `service1;service2;service3` into the service column? If so, use PHPs `explode()` function

```
$var = "service1;service2;service3";
$result = explode(";", $var);

var_dump($result)
```

Now you can iterate through the array and replace each service with some image/list item or whatever. It should work like that, although I didn't test it:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $service_array = explode(",", $row[services]);
    echo "<div class='portfolio_block'><h3>Services</h3>";

    if(count($services)) {
        echo "<ul>";

        foreach($service_array as $service) {
            echo "<li>" . $service . "</li>";
        }

        echo "</ul>"
    }

    echo "</div>";
}
```

I would also recommend taking Jamies advice and switch from `mysql_*` functions to PDO. And for "styling" the list items add some class tags :)

Comment: Hi Nephix,

My current script can be found here: http://davidpottrell.co.uk/paste/portfolio.txt

I've never heard of explode before - Is there a way to implement it into my current work?

Comment: What is the output of `$row[services]` and `$row[colours]`? :)

Comment: $row[services] echoes: SEO Management, Branding/Illustration, Graphic Design $row[colours] echoes: blue, purple, grey, green

Comment: Ah ok and your current script outputs you what? Like `SEO Management,Graphic Design` or how is it formatted? Same for the colors

Comment: Currently, it only outputs whatever is in the services/colour field. For example, client1 has colours **white, black** and services, **Graphic Design** - I'd like it so the colours are printed as 16x16 colour blocks and services in a list. No formatting currently on it

Comment: http://www.davidpottrell.co.uk/paste/todo.png

this is what I have right now and what i'm after

Comment: Think I need to research some more - Can't seem to figure out how to implement your code into mine. Not sure where to place it :/